# Installing Jenkins on Tomcat8 and Tomcat9 on same machine

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, deployment, automation, workspace

I have installed Jenkins on the server on Tomcat8 by copying war file to the webapps folder. The directory structure of Tomcat 8 is C:/Tomcat8/.

After deploying the war the JENKINS_HOME directory is "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.jenkins".

Now i am installing Tomcat 9 on C:/Tomacat9,copied and deployed the war file to Tomcat9.

After deploying Jenkins to Tomcat9, it is interfering with the JENKINS_HOME directory above.Both jenkins are using the same Jenkins directory.

How do i direct my second Jenkins instance to not use the same JENKINS_HOME directory ?